# How do I run a dockerized 'Hello World' web job deployed into Virtual Kubelet within Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)

Tags: azure, docker, kubectl, azure-aks

I did create a simple 'Hello World' Web Job and placed that Web Job inside a Docker Windows Container/Nanoserver

I did push that Docker Windows Container into an Azure Container Registry

I did follow this article and successfully created Virtual AKS pods/nodes

When I run 'get pods' I do see the pods created and running

I do see IP's generated reflected in the 'get pods' command

My question is how do I run the container inside these pods/nodes?

I did try to reference the IP's but those IP's don't load anything

How can I run those containers that I successfully placed into Virtual Kubelet pods/nodes

If the containers in the get fired up by themselves, do they fire up/get invoked only once or every n number of minutes?

Is there a way to check on how the last run went, like log files?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Any more questions? Or if it's helpful you can accept it as the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Someone mentioned at some point that I can use Virtual AKS for Windows containers.

Is that the case?

Comment: Update the solution below to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I see you create your web job inside a Windows-based Docker. If so, you cannot run the container in the AKS while it does not support Windows nodes, at least current. For window container, I suggest you could use the [Azure Container Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-overview) or [Web App for Container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-windows-container).

For Linux containers, the pod in AKS is a group of one or more containers (such as Docker containers), with shared storage/network, and a specification for how to run the containers. If you already have the Docker image, you can create the container inside the pod follow the steps in [Running the application in AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough#run-the-application).

In addition, you can set the restart policy for your container. See [Restart Policy for the container in Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy). For the logs, I suggest you could use the persist volumes. If not, the files will be lost if the container crash.\

**Update**

If you really want to run windows container in AKS cluster, there is also a way for you. You can use the virtual Kubelet and Azure Container Instance in AKS. Follow the steps [Run Windows container in AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/virtual-kubelet#run-windows-container).